# Eclipse CDT - new Makefile project with existing code - change global default build target

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have existing code with their own makefiles which I want to load into Eclipse CDT.

This is simple enough - Just create a new Makefile project with existing code.

However, I would like to manage what defaults are chosen for certain settings.

For instance the default build target is 'all'.

At the moment I have to manually change this for every single project.

Is there any way to specify project defaults which are used every time I create a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.7.2:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> New CDT Project Wizard -> Makefile Project -> Behaviour [tab].

Comment: I've done this but it doesn't seem to store the settings - new makefile projects revert to the standard defaults... is there a trick to getting this behaviour?

Comment: "Preference settings will be applied to new projects only when there were no toolchains selected." - may be, this is an issue.